# Bring browser find text in active view with embedded html

Tags: javascript, html

I have an embedded Iframe with Html on my page , when I search text from browser crtl+f function , it finds texts in my embedded html , but if the found text is not in active view , it does not scroll to it. I added this javascript to my iframe to scroll to text but it doesnt work. Can someone point out what is missing here

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Sample HTML Page with Search Functionality</title>
       <!-- Add a new class for highlighting the current word -->
    <style>
        .highlight {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        .current-word-highlight {
            background-color: yellow;
            color: red; /* Optional: Change the text color for better visibility */
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to the Sample Page</h1>
    
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sit amet lacus ac dolor mattis volutpat. Proin sit amet efficitur metus. Sed id velit ut dolor suscipit ultricies. Integer non ex eu risus iaculis viverra. Fusce a tortor sit amet odio laoreet bibendum. Phasellus ac arcu a nulla lacinia auctor a id dui. Quisque tincidunt sapien a augue vestibulum, sit amet bibendum dolor ultrices. Praesent congue, enim vel hendrerit mattis, urna ipsum pharetra nunc, nec dapibus libero dolor a libero.</p>
    
        <p>Suspendisse potenti. Donec ultricies cursus quam, at hendrerit justo pharetra a. Fusce facilisis quam eget turpis elementum tincidunt. Sed ut pharetra metus. Morbi feugiat velit id quam sollicitudin, ac condimentum urna viverra. Maecenas fringilla ultricies euismod. In at orci vel felis ultricies dictum. Nulla facilisi. Sed in tellus felis. Vivamus et ligula ut quam laoreet eleifend. Nullam tincidunt urna vel eros egestas dapibus.</p>
    
        <p>Integer vitae arcu nec tortor pharetra tincidunt. Sed id metus nec dui facilisis fermentum. Sed in eleifend justo. Fusce commodo ac tortor non feugiat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus ac scelerisque massa, sit amet tincidunt odio. Nullam eget auctor eros, vel tristique odio. Etiam tristique tristique ligula, et feugiat erat viverra vel.</p>
    
        <p>Quisque sit amet consectetur lorem. Suspendisse nec lorem quam. Vestibulum congue metus id luctus ullamcorper. Sed tincidunt, tortor id hendrerit ultricies, elit urna aliquet purus, non posuere nulla tortor in libero. Proin ac orci eu urna fringilla tincidunt a quis arcu. Sed rhoncus, ipsum vel facilisis congue, arcu risus tempus metus, nec consequat lectus ipsum id purus.</p>
    
        <p>Donec volutpat non quam eu laoreet. Sed sed metus et felis rhoncus vehicula. Fusce efficitur tristique mi, sit amet consectetur elit posuere eget. Nam vel dui sed urna tempus efficitur. Nulla facilisi. Donec nec congue neque. Suspendisse a ipsum ante. Praesent sit amet quam quis erat mattis fringilla nec id sapien. Integer nec metus eu est faucibus hendrerit in non nunc. Fusce vel lacinia odio, sit amet scelerisque ligula. Fusce ac odio mi.</p>
    
        <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search within the page">
        <button id="search-button">Find</button>
        <button id="next-button">Next</button>
        <button id="prev-button">Previous</button>
    
        <script>
            const searchInput = document.getElementById("search-input");
            const searchButton = document.getElementById("search-button");
            const nextButton = document.getElementById("next-button");
            const prevButton = document.getElementById("prev-button");
            const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");
            let currentIndex = -1;
    
            searchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                const searchTerm = searchInput.value.toLowerCase();
                currentIndex = -1;
    
                if (searchTerm === "") {
                    clearHighlights();
                    return;
                }
    
                const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${searchTerm}\\b`, "ig");
                const textToSearch = Array.from(paragraphs).map(p => p.textContent).join("\n");
                const matches = [...textToSearch.matchAll(regex)];
    
                if (matches.length > 0) {
                    clearHighlights();
                    highlightMatches(matches);
                    currentIndex = 0;
                } else {
                    clearHighlights();
                    alert("No matches found.");
                }
            });
    
            
    // Add this code to load and search within external text files
function searchExternalFiles(searchTerm) {
    const objectElements = document.querySelectorAll("object");

    objectElements.forEach(async (objectElement) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(objectElement.data);
            const text = await response.text();
            const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${searchTerm}\\b`, "ig");
            const matches = [...text.matchAll(regex)];

            if (matches.length > 0) {
                const contentDocument = objectElement.contentDocument;
                const content = contentDocument.body.textContent;

                matches.forEach(match => {
                    const { index } = match;
                    const startIndex = index;
                    const matchedText = content.substr(startIndex, searchTerm.length);

                    contentDocument.body.innerHTML = content.substring(0, startIndex) +
                        `<span class="highlight">${matchedText}</span>` +
                        content.substring(startIndex + matchedText.length);
                });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error loading or searching within external file:", error);
        }
    });
}

// Modify the searchButton click event to include external files
searchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const searchTerm = searchInput.value.toLowerCase();
    currentIndex = -1;

    if (searchTerm === "") {
        clearHighlights();
        return;
    }

    // Search within paragraphs in the main HTML file
    searchWithinParagraphs(searchTerm);

    // Search within external files loaded via object tags
    searchExternalFiles(searchTerm);
});

            function clearHighlights() {
                paragraphs.forEach(p => {
                    p.innerHTML = p.textContent;
                    p.classList.remove("highlight");
                });
            }
    
            function highlightMatches(matches) {
                matches.forEach(match => {
                    const { index, input } = match;
                    const paragraphIndex = getParagraphIndex(input, index);
                    const paragraph = paragraphs[paragraphIndex];
                    const startIndex = index - input.lastIndexOf("\n", index) + 1;
                    const matchedText = input.substr(index, searchInput.value.length);
    
                    const highlightedMatch = paragraph.innerHTML.substring(0, startIndex) +
                        `<span class="highlight">${matchedText}</span>` +
                        paragraph.innerHTML.substring(startIndex + matchedText.length);
    
                    paragraph.innerHTML = highlightedMatch;
                });
            }
    
            function getParagraphIndex(text, index) {
                const beforeText = text.substring(0, index);
                return beforeText.split("\n").length - 1;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So are you using the built-in search (as you mention) or your own one? If it's your own one, then I don't see any code that would scroll it into view, and you are replacing all the HTML on a page just to add a highlight, which would reset the page quite a bit. If it's the latter there's not much you can do.